# What kind of optical activity requires chirality?

Tags: chirality, isomers, optical-properties

From "[Meso compound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meso_compound)" in Wikipedia:

> A meso compound or meso isomer is a **non-optically active** member of a
>   set of stereoisomers, at least two of which are optically active. This
>   means that despite containing two or more stereogenic centers, the
>   molecule is not chiral.

What is the meaning of "optical activity" in this context? In other words, what kind of photo activity requires chirality?

Comment: Chirality can be observed by the way a beam of light is refracted after passing it through a solution of the subject compound

Comment: Rotation of plane of polarised light, as always.

Answer (score 5):

The meaning of optical activity in this context is the same as usual: the ability to rotate the plane of polarized light. To have it, a molecule must be chiral.

Chirality is the **absence** of certain type of symmetry. Since most *small* molecules have that symmetry, many students get the wrong perception that chirality is a property which must be obtained by having some functional group (asymmetric center, etc.), much like having a $\ce{-COOH}$ group makes a compound an acid. This is not quite true. Not only a compound may be chiral without any chiral centers, but it can also be achiral despite having some chiral centers, as are meso compounds.