# Is it possible to generalize whether an organic molecule is chiral or not?

Tags: stereochemistry, chirality

Can we generalize on the basis of number of chirality centers  if an organic molecule is chiral or not?

Comment: Chirality in general is not about centers. There can be centers without chirality, as well as chirality without centers. Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39830/what-kind-of-optical-activity-requires-chirality/39833#39833

Answer (score 3):

There is a general statement. If the molecule has any improper axis of rotation, it is achiral.

Comment: What is an "improper" axis of rotation  by the way. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Rotation + reflection through a plane perpendicular to the axis. If you can do that to the molecule and have it look exactly the same. It is not chiral.