# Why was the definition of chiral carbon changed?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality

Before 1984, the definition of **chiral carbon** was,

> *carbon atom that is attached to four different types of atoms or
>   groups of atoms*

In 1984, the definition was changed to

> *Any carbon molecule that is not superimposable on its mirror image.*

Why was this change made? Don't both definitions mean the same or is/are there cases where the former is false. Preferably, please provide an **example**

Comment: The second definition is much broader. An object which is not superimposable with its mirror image does not have to be carbon, or any atom, for that matter. Your left hand is an example of such object.

Comment: how is it broader? what do you mean by the second sentence @IvanNeretin

Comment: Now that you've changed the definition, your left hand is no longer an example. Still, the second definition is broader (there are chiral molecules in which no carbon is attached to four different groups). Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39830/what-kind-of-optical-activity-requires-chirality/39833#39833

Comment: No! The first statement is entirely incorrect as 1. there are carbons with four different substituents that are achiral and 2. there are chiral molecules with less than four different substituents. Meaning that the first definition is **entirely wrong** in _both directions_. By the way, the second definition is not really wrong, but it is missing the point that it is the existance of any $S_n$ element that renders a molecule achiral. Please be precise here.

Comment: Martin and I both spent some time discussing the definition of chirality here: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/59124/what-is-the-perfect-definition-for-chirality/59144#59144

Answer (score 3):

The IUPAC definition of **[asymmetric carbon](http://goldbook.iupac.org/PDF/A00479.pdf)** is still:

> The traditional name (van't Hoff) for a carbon atom that is attached to four different entities (atoms or groups), e.g. Cabcd.

The definition of **[chirality centre](https://www.iupac.org/goldbook/C01060.pdf)** is:

> An atom holding a set of ligands in a spatial arrangement which is not superposable
>   on its mirror image. A chirality centre is thus a generalized extension of the concept
>   of the asymmetric carbon atom to central atoms of any element, for example N+abcd,
>   Pabc as well as Cabcd.

Comment: Asymmetric carbon is a complete misnomer because the carbon atom is indeed very symmetric (spherical symmetry). And again, chirality centre is bad for the same reasons (see my answer). Does it make sense to define a chirality centre in a way that it can also be contained in non-chiral molecules? And even so that a molecule can be chiral without having a chirality centre? How can that ever be a sensible definition! The IUPAC gold book also gives those definitions as "traditional names" (see http://goldbook.iupac.org/S05980.html).

Comment: @ketbra yes it makes sense to me.  The local environment at the carbon is asymmetrical, yet the molecule may or may not be chiral.  See Le Bel-van't Hoff rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bel-van%27t_Hoff_rule It made sense in 1874.  It still makes sense.

Comment: I just don't get it, sorry. The 'local environment at the carbon is asymmetrical' don't cause even more confusion because that is already covered by the term chirotopic.

Comment: By the way if you say it like that, then most of the carbon atoms would be asymmetrical carbons, as all atoms in a chiral molecule are in a chiral environment, so then all atoms of a chiral molecule would be chiral centers, isnt that kind of confusing. Why not just stick with the clearcut $S_n$ definition then?

Comment: @ketbra "The crux of the matter is that chirotopicity and stereogenicity
are conceptually distinct; consider, for example, the halogen atoms
in CHBrClF (chirotopic but nonstereogenic) and the carbon atoms
in the CHCl groups of 1,2-dichloroethene (achirotopic but stereogenic).
Nevertheless, stereogenicity and local chirality appear
to be inseparably linked in the practice of organic chemistry, as
epitomized by the very expression “asymmetric carbon atom”." http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00323a043

Comment: Taking cis-1,2-Dimethylcyclohexane as an example. You think it is reasonable that this molecule contains two chiral centers even though it is achiral? And please explain to me why it is reasonable to have a chiral molecule and always achiral atoms and then to speak of a chiral carbon atom even though it is *clearly achiral* and only (in some cases) chirotopic.

Comment: Sure, stereogenicity and chirotopicity are completely different. I mean a double bond for example may have stereocenters as well. Still it makes much more sense to have sometimes achiral molecules with stereogenic centers than to have achiral molecules with chiral centers. I just prefer the short and correct definition (existance of $S_n$) over the long clumsy and wrong one with 'four substituents'.

Comment: @ketbra like the "Stereoisomerism and Local Chirality" article explains, the point of the term "asymmetric carbon" is describe local chirality.

Comment: But if asymmetric carbon describes local chirality how is it different from chirotopicity?

Comment: @ketbra chirotopic refers to an atom or other entity in a chiral situation http://old.iupac.org/goldbook/C01065.pdf so it is global. See also the quote a few comments above "...halogen atoms in CHBrClF..."

Comment: This discussion leads nowhere. My point is, if the carbon is not asymmetric than it is wrong to call it asymmetric carbon. If I say "the kitchen is painted red" than I mean that the kitchen is red and not the house surrounding it. If a carbon atom is not asymmetric and also not chiral and it is termed either asymmetric carbon or chiral center even though it is _the surrounding_ that is asymmetric/chiral than this is a clear case of a misnomer to me, and that's it. If you don't agree with that logic please tell me why but please stop given references that have nothing to do with the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The first definition is entirely wrong. Take cis-1,2-dimethylcyclohexane as an example. While any of the two tertiary carbons bears four different substituents the molecule is achiral. Then there are molecules (like helicene, BINAP, ...) that have no atoms with four different substituents and are chiral nonethless. So the definition of chirality based on four different substituents is **entirely wrong**. Then there is the problem that the expression 'chiral carbon' implies that the *carbon itself* is somehow chiral, which it is of course not, but it is the molecule which is chiral instead. This is why use of the terms 'chiral carbon' and 'chirality center' is discouraged. The correct term is stereogenic center, avoiding those issues alltogether. The second definition is also not good, as it isn't clear what superimposable means. Just use the clearcut definition that an achiral molecules point group contains $S_n$ with $n \geq 1$ elements and that's it!

Comment: So basically, if you still use the terms 'chirality center' or 'achiral carbon' or whatever you might end up in the paradoxical (but funny) situation of having an achiral molecule that contains one or even multiple 'chirality centers'. How is that a sensible definition?

Comment: your first point _...helicene, BINAP, ...) that have no atoms with four different substituents and are chiral nonethless_ is unjustified because if 1-> 2 in not necessary equal to 2->1 EDIT: Im sorry, i understood what you meant